# How to print the index numbers of rows and columns alongside the values?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROQ4H.png) I am trying to print out edges of the data in an excel file. I got the values to print. But I am unable to print the row and column indexes because of looping over the dataframe.

I tried printing using `df.index` but it gives out the range of the rows as follows:
`5.0 RangeIndex(start=4, stop=30, step=1)` where `5` is the edge value and the latter is the index.

```
    df = wb.iloc[rows, coln].fillna(0)
    dfa = df.to_numpy()
    for row in dfa:
        for value in row:
            if value!=0:
                print(value, df.index)
                break
```

```
This is the expexted result.
```

`5 11 15.0`

```
where 5 is the row number, 11 is the column number and 15.0 is the value on that cell.
```

I tried using the iterrows() function by looping over df as follows and I got it to print out the row numbers alongside the cell values.

```
df = wb.iloc[rows, coln].fillna(0)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

Still no progress on the column numbers though.

Comment: is wb your 2D data?

Comment: No, the data is unstructured. I'll edit and upload image.

Comment: So are you reading in an xml into a dataframe?

Comment: No it is a xlsx file. I've uploaded the screenshot in the description.

Comment: oops I meant to type excel not xml, my bad.

Comment: Yeah, even I got confused at first. I'm new to pandas and python so it's difficult.

Comment: Is your goal just to print it as row column value?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my goal is simply to get the row, column and value (for each value),
I would convert it into a numpy array and apply ndenumerate() as below :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] #Assuming my data looks like d
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
na = np.array(df)

for index, value in np.ndenumerate(na):
  print(index, value)

(0, 0) 1
(0, 1) 2
(1, 0) 3
(1, 1) 4
(2, 0) 5
(2, 1) 6
```

(OR)

```
for index, value in np.ndenumerate(na):
  print(index[0], index[1], value)


0 0 1
0 1 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
2 0 5
2 1 6
```

I hope that helps!